# Unable to fetch error response code in volley

Tags: android, http-headers, android-volley

My application requires login of user. It is working fine for successful login. But, in case of an error, error 400 is returned, but only error listener is invoked. I am not able to read the status code. I want to read the error response code, so as to show specific error toast to the user.

My code is :-

```
    String SignInURL = "https://xyz/abc";

    StringRequest j1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,SignInURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GG"+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.e("QWER",""+jsonResponse);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+jsonResponse,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    sp = getSharedPreferences(AUTHDATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("access_token",jsonResponse.getString("access_token"));
                    edit.putString("token_type",jsonResponse.getString("token_type"));
                    edit.putString("refresh_token",jsonResponse.getString("refresh_token"));
                    edit.putString("scope",jsonResponse.getString("scope"));
                    Log.e("ACCESS_TOKEN",jsonResponse.getString("access_token"));
                    if(jsonResponse.getString("access_token").equals("")){
                        edit.putBoolean("login",false);
                    }else{edit.putBoolean("login",true);}
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return hashMap;
        }

    };


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(j1);
```

Comment: you are getting an exception in your response listener, that the catch block is catching with exception 400.

Comment: Nopes, on ErrorResponse is handling it. I get "Invalid Credentials" toast which is in scope of ErrorResponse

Comment: add ur JSON value here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after a long struggle find the answer to it.
Simply add

```
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       int statcod = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
       switch(statcode){
       case 400:
       //code you want to run for error status 400
       break;
       case 500:
       //code you want to run for error status 400
       break;
       default :
       //default code
       }
    }
```